# DAX l POWERBI l Rankx Filter very slow

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have performance issues with the Rankx function.

Currently, i use the rankx function for a dynamic top n selection for a matrix with a slicer.

This works fine for a table with less than 200 customers.
However, if i use my table with 15000 customers, the matrix will not load.
What is also confusing is that this filter works well for a piechart but not for a matrix.

I would be really glad for suggestions or workarounds.

The DAX for my rankx function is the following:

**Rank__Customer = RANKX(ALL(Customer[CustomerName] ),[TotalSales])**

Comment: Import or DirectQuery?  How many rows in the sales table?

Comment: Go to view --> show panes --> Run Performance Analyzer. On the upper right corner, Click Export . Now share that performance data in JSON format. Do not be worried. It is only performance data, does not include your actual data. With your given info above , It is impossible to offer a solution.